# Communicating "which playing card" between View and Model - best way?

Tags: swift

For fun I'm building a FreeCell solitaire game from scratch in Swift. I've got my model for the deck set up to build the deck and each Card struct has a suit, rank, and description (e.g., 4♠️) plus some other properties. The model for the game simply stores what cards are in what columns. A change in the view (moving a card) will alert the controller to modify what cards are in what columns.

When a user taps on the card (a subclass of UIView including a label that contains card.description) the label.text will be sent to the controller to identify the card in the model. I'm wondering what the best way to do this is.

The most obvious way I can think of is to build dictionary where the keys are descriptions and the values are cards. I can write a function in my DeckBuilder class to build the dictionary for me, of course. But since the description already exists as a property of the Card struct, this seems a little redundant and clunky-ish.

Another method would be to, every time a card is selected, iterate through the deck of cards in the model and say "if selectedCard.description == tryCard.description { //this is the right card! } " but that seems absurdly inelegant and theoretically too computationally expensive (although in reality I'm sure it takes no time at all).

What I'd love to do is have the controller say "get the Card that has this String as its description property." Similar to dictionary lookup, but without an actual dictionary.

Is this last solution possible? If not, what do you think is best?

Thankya!

Answer (score 1):

You should not use the text of a label as an indication of a value at some location; this is like storing your model in your view. Instead you have come internal structure that represents the state of the columns.  Each column can be an array of cards.  The columns themselves can be in an array of columns:

```
    struct Card {}
    var deck = [Card]()
    var columns: [[Card]] = [[Card]](repeating: [], count: 7)
    deck.shuffle()
    for i in 0..<columns.count {
        for j in 0..<i {
            columns[i].append(deck.draw())
        }
    }
```

Now if you have a click on a view. you just need to know what column and what index in that column was clicked (you can do this based on the frame of the view or by assigning a tag to each view).  You can now get the value of the card but looking at the columns array: columns[selectedColumn][selectedRow]

Comment: Thanks! That does seem to be a much better way to communicate between the model and the view.

Answer (score 1):

I would create two enums, one for the rank and one for the suit.

```
enum Rank {
    case value(Int)
    case jack
    case queen
    case king
    case ace
}

enum Suit {
   case diamond
   case heart
   case spade
   case club
}
```

This is way safer and more readable than a dictionary. In your struct Card you can add these two properties.

```
struct Card {
    var rank: Rank
    var suit: Suit
}
```

It's up to you if you want to compare the Strings, compare the enums or even have your Card struct conform to the Equatable protocol. I would probably go for the Equatable protocol but I do not think that there are big differences between these options.